# AttributeError trying to automate WhatsApp using Selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui  import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Edge(r"C:\Users\Manan\Downloads\edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver") 
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,600)
target = "Dad"
string = "message send from manan!!"
x_arg ='//span[contains(@title,'+ target + ')]'
target = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, x_arg)))
target.click()
```

Can someone help out? I am a beginner and it always gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Answer (score 1):

`presence_of_all_elements_located` returns a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) of WebElements. That means there are more than one element in `target`. You must first select which of those WebElements you'd like to click, or click them all:

```
targets = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, x_arg)))
target = targets[0] # Select first one
target.click()
```

```
targets = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, x_arg)))
for target in targets: # Loop over and click each one
    target.click()
```

See: [docs on `presence_of_all_elements_located`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located)